# How to: Contact form autofill email and username of logged in user

Tags: php

Normally when I build form I include 'email' and 'name' fields and when visitors fill them in I get there name and email as it was intended.

But now I build offline website just for registered users, now contact form can see just logged in user and I want to leave those fields out, it could be frustrating when you are logged in and you have to fill your name and email all over again.

Is it possible to somehow fetch email off logged in user and put it in the form so i would know which of logged in users has sent the form?

- I use my own code - not joomla or wordpress

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Do you not store the name or email anywhere?

Comment: Do you want when user login his email id goes to form field entry and user donot require to enter the value

Comment: @arxanas I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. In MSQL DB I have table 'siteusr' and column 'login' is user name and column 'email' for email adress.

Comment: @Alex So what happens when you retrieve those?

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava - Yes something like that. But for login I ask users for user name and password not email.

Comment: @Alex then get email from database and get to next page of form like form.php?id=<your email id>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the value of the email address input field on the contact field to that of the logged in user's email address. I can't tell you how to do that exactly without seeing your codebase, but it will be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($user->getEmail()) ?>">
```